# List of Privileges Considered for Standard User As "Additional Privileges" for Windows UAC

Tags: windows, permissions, uac

I am trying to understand some behavior I am seeing with Windows User Account Control (UAC).  We have an application that is being run with the manifest `requestedExecutionLevel` `highestAvailable`.

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

I have full UAC enabled on my machine.  When I run this application as a local user, Windows does not prompt me to elevate privileges.  This is expected behavior.

When I run this application as an administrator, Windows prompts me to elevate privileges.  This is also expected behavior.

However, when I login to my workstation as a domain user that is a standard user account, the domain user is also prompted to elevate privileges.  This is what I am trying to understand.

According to several sources I have read, the UAC consent behavior is slightly different for users that have additional privileges.  For example, from [Windows Vista Application Development Requirements for User Account Control Compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx), "**A standard user with additional privileges (such as backup operator)**" (emphasis mine) will be prompted for consent if the consent policy is to prompt for credentials.

I want to get more information about which "additional privileges" would cause the user to be prompted for UAC consent.  I can imagine some of them are Power users, Backup Operators, Domain Admins, Account Operators, etc.  Ideally, there is a list or table somewhere out there of what would trigger this consent behavior.

**What "additional privileges" would trigger UAC consent popups for standard user accounts?**

Answer (score 1):

According to this TechNet article by Mark Russinovich, [Security: Inside Windows Vista User Account Control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.uac.aspx), the list of additional privileges is:

- Built-In Administrators
- Certificate Administrators
- Domain Administrators
- Enterprise Administrators
- Policy Administrators
- Schema Administrators
- Domain Controllers
- Enterprise Read-Only Domain Controllers
- Read-Only Domain Controllers
- Account Operators
- Backup Operators
- Cryptographic Operators
- Network Configuration Operators
- Print Operators
- System Operators
- RAS Servers
- Power Users
- Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access